# FROM Statement Giving an Error (3 Sources)

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to SELECT a few things from tables A,B, and C, but when I try to LEFT JOIN, I keep getting an error. My code currently looks like this:

```
FROM (A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id), C
```

Am I not allowed to left join two tables and include the entirety of a third?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**
Here is a sample code:

`SELECT A.ID, A.place, A.receipt, D.State, A.service, B.Description,  C.ID, C.receipt, C.Source
FROM B, (A LEFT JOIN C ON A.receipt = C.receipt), D;`

Comment: `...FROM ((A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id) INNER JOIN C ON ...)`?

Comment: Table C doesn't have anything in common with the other 2, I just wanted to select a column or two from table C.

Comment: No relation? Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Comment: @Parfait, I am getting an error that reads "JOIN expression not supported."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access doesn't support combining cross-joins with other joins, so you will have to do the left join in a subquery, and then the cross-join:

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.id) As D, C
```

Comment: I do not want to select every column from A or B though, these tables pull from a database and have over 100 columns -- I just want the ones I need for the query.

Comment: Well obviously, you can define which columns you want. Just adjust the * to a list of columns.